# Filtering a custom list on a visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, help

Any ideas whats wrong with my code i am trying to filter a custom list on a visual force page. Thank you inm advance.

Apex Class:

```
       Public class IssueController {


 Private String baseQuery = 'SELECT Unique_Issue_Number__C, Issue_Status__C,Issue_Type__C, Systems_Member_Dealing_With_Issue__c,FROM Issue__C';
 public String IssFilterID { get; set; }
 Private Integer pageSize = 10;

public IssueController(){}

Public ApexPages.StandardSetController IssSetController{
get{
    if(IssSetController == null){
        IssSetController = new
ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(baseQuery));
    IssSetController.SetPageSize(pageSize);

    if(IssFilterId != null)
    {
     IssSetController.setFilterId(IssFilterId);
     }
     }
     return IssSetController;
  }set;
  }
  Public IssueController(ApexPages.StandardSetController c){  } 

  public Class SampleNam{
     String[] Options = new String []{};

 public List<SelectOption> getItems()
{
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
options.add(new SelectOption('Jack Sawyer','Jack Sawyer'));
options.add(new SelectOption('Ian Paddon','Ian Paddon'));
options.add(new SelectOption('Rachel Eley','Rachel Eley'));
options.add(new SelectOption('Yana Griffiths','Yana Griffiths'));
options.add(new SelectOption('Tracey Greenwood-Wright','Tracey Greenwood-Wright'));
}
Public String [] getOptions() {
return Options;
}
}
}
```

Visual force page:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Issue__c" recordSetVar="Issue__c">
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="Issue List" id="Issue_list" >

<apex:selectList id="Filter" value="{!Options}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Jack Sawyer" itemLabel="Jack Sawyer"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Ian Paddon" itemLabel="Ian Paddon"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Rachel Eley" itemLabel="Rachel Eley"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yana Griffiths" itemLabel="Yana Griffiths"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="Tracey Greenwood-Wright"         itemLabel="Tracey Greenwood-Wright"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Issue_List"/>
     </apex:selectList>

    <!-- Issue List -->
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! Issue__c }" var="ct">
   <apex:column headerValue="Unique Issue Number">
   <apex:outputLink value="/{!ct.id}" target="_blank/" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!ct.Unique_Issue_Number__c}">
</apex:outputText>
</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{! ct.Issue_Status__c }"/>     
<apex:column value="{! ct.Issue_Type__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{! ct.Systems_Member_Dealing_With_Issue__c}"/>

 </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:PageBlock>
 </Apex:form>
  </Apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you give us a clue as to what is happening? Or why you think this is behaving "wrong" - it's a lot easier to help find the problem if we know what it is... otherwise we have to read every character of code and try to imagine what it's doing!

Comment: I am new to Apex coding and using Visualforce  but what i think is the issue is the way i have selected my options. What i am trying to achieve is from my custom Block table i would like to filter the results by the Systems_Member_Dealing_With_Issue__c field i didn't know a direct way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: The Errors i get are related to the "Value" of the select list on the Visual force page and  this error on the apex class:  Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 37 column 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie doke.. step 1, the syntax error from your comment:

> Error: Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 37 column 5

is because in your inner class `SampleNam` - you are defining a method called `getItems` with return type of a list, but you never return anything.

If you add `return options;` at line 38 you will get past this and be able to save the file..

```
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Jack Sawyer','Jack Sawyer'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Ian Paddon','Ian Paddon'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Rachel Eley','Rachel Eley'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Yana Griffiths','Yana Griffiths'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Tracey Greenwood-Wright','Tracey Greenwood-Wright'));
        return options;
    }
```

Which is a start.

Thing is, I can't actually work out what `SampleNam` is supposed to be doing I'm afraid! It looks a bit like a couple of examples pasted together perhaps at the moment? The standardSetController, inner class `SampleNam` don't really gel, and I am finding it hard to tether the Apex stuff to what's on the Visualforce page!

Also, the StandardSetController setFilterId is expecting to receive a List View Id from the Salesforce Metadata for that object, but you aren't setting this anywhere, and the instance of the setController (`IssSetController`) isn't referenced on your Visualforce.

Either way, I hope the little fix for the method return keeps your wheels turning, with lots of googling (and maybe a few more questions on here!) you will get there! :)

Comment: Thank you Simon, I suppose the next question i would have is,  how would i set the list view Id for a custom object ? and how would you reference the issSet controller in the Visual page ? Thak you for all your help with this been googling for days getting many different examples as you can tell from the miss matched code.

Comment: I didn't even spot the controller wasn't applied to the page! on the apex:page tag use `extensions=IssueController` - and it will start using it. Playing with listviews in apex is really hard. granted! You are sure what you want is to replicate the filtering of a standard list view from the object Tab page on your picklist in Visualforce? Have you been on/through Trailhead? I think a few hours of apex modules might serve you as well as thrashing through a very difficult piece of functional work: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers

Comment: I have completed all of the modules on trialhead regarding this but when i started to use my own custom objects and Tabs it all got really confusing and i kept getting the error of unknown Properties. As an end result i want the ability to see all cases and filter by person who they relate to hence the column for Systems member dealing with issue. Thank you again for your help i am slowly getting there :).